# Using my laptop as a router for a VM and embedded computer?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, vmware, nat

I've got a laptop running 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium with Ubuntu 12.04LTS on VMWare Player. Connected via a crossover cable to the laptop is a Raspberry Pi, which uses my laptop's shared internet connection to apt-get packages off the school network. This is to avoid having to store authentication information on the Raspberry Pi. This works and I can ping and ssh the Pi from within Windows, however I need to be able to do the same from within the VM which can't see the Pi. A quick IPConfig shows that VMNet1, VMNet8, and Ethernet are all on different subnets (which explains why they can't see each other) but trying to manually issue IPs (for example 192.168.3.x) isn't working. How do I set up a NAT within Windows so that the VM, Pi and W7 can all talk to each other and access the internet? Can it even be done in Home Premium?

If all else fails I'll repartition the drive and double boot Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Disclaimer: I'm not very good at networking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to do this in Windows 7 Home Premium. Server 2008 will do it, but it's just more straightforward to double boot the VM OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the network adapter for the VM in VMware Player from "NAT" to "bridged", the VM will get an IP on the same network as your laptop, and you should be able to connect with the Pi.

But that will probably require the VM to authenticate to the network.  What are the IP settings on the Pi?

Comment: Ethernet settings are default/automatic for the Pi. Plug it in, it gets an IP address from my laptop.